# How to conditionally remove a value from a javascript object during a setState call in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, setstate

```js
updateDishDetails(id, quantity) {

    if (quantity !== 0) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          bookingFormData: {
            ...prevState.bookingFormData,
            dishDetails: {
              ...prevState.bookingFormData.dishDetails,      // WORKING
              [id]: quantity,                                // PERFECTLY
            },
          },
        })
      );
    }

   if (quantity === 0) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          bookingFormData: {
            ...prevState.bookingFormData,
            dishDetails: {
             // ...prevState.bookingFormData.dishDetails,   // NEED HELP HERE
            // [id]: quantity,                             // AND HERE
            },
          },
        })
      );
    }

  }
```

I have the above function where I set the state of **dishDetails** based on the value of quantity.

What do I want to achieve?

1. When the quantity !== 0 set the state of dishDetails as shown. *( This is working Perfectly )*
2. When the quantity === 0, I want to remove that particular id from the **dishDetails**, but the previous state should be maintained. *( I need help in solving this )*

The relevant state is a follows:

```js
this.state = {
   bookingFormData: {
      dishDetails: []
   }
}
```

Comment: you have dish details as an array and an object in the examples above

Comment: can you provide some sample for the dishDetails list, its looks confusing, because in code its shows like object, but below state information, you mentioned as arrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use destructuring assignment and the rest operator to create a new object and remove a prop :

```
if (quantity === 0) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => {
          const { [id]: removedId, ...newDishDetails } = prevState.bookingFormData.dishDetails;
          return {
            bookingFormData: {
              ...prevState.bookingFormData,
              dishDetails: newDishDetails,
            },
          },
        }
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Can you nullify the id?

Set the id's value to null to remove the content.

```
dishDetails: {
  ...prevState.bookingFormData.dishDetails,
  [id]: null,
},
```

if its an array thats easier

```
dishDetails: {
  ...prevState.bookingFormData.dishDetails.filter((item) => item.id !== id),
},
```

or if input and output are both objects

```
dishDetails: {
  ...Object.entries(prevState.bookingFormData.dishDetails)
    .filter(([key, item]) => item.id !== id)
    .reduce((acc, [key, item]) => ({...acc, [key]: item}), {}),
},
```

Comment: Will nulling the [id] remove that specific ID completely? or will is show as ```{id: null}```

Comment: Exactly ! I would like to completely remove that specific id from the object. Any way to achieve that @Joe Lloyd?

Comment: turn you object to an array with entries, then filter, then reduce back to object

Comment: will doing this, remove the ID from the object when quantity === 0? after doing this.

Comment: if you put it in the if statement `if (quantity === 0) { ` then yes it will do that.

Comment: I tried it out man, It isnt removing that specific ID from the object, but still thanks alot of the effort, the other solution worked for me. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'll use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```
if (quantity === 0) {
 const dishDetails = {...this.state.bookingFormData.dishDetails}
 delete dishDetails[id];

this.setState(
  prevState => ({
    bookingFormData: {
      ...prevState.bookingFormData,
      dishDetails
   }
  })
 )
}
```

Comment: Do i have to write lines 3 & 4 inside setState ? because I am getting this error: 'prevState' is not defined

Comment: My bad, `prevState` is inside the setState, so you can use `this.state.bookingFormData.dishDetails`

Comment: Never use delete in react when state is involved. it mutates. I know you have a spread to copy but its a shallow copy and we dont know whats inside dishDetails.

Comment: This isnt working my friend. btw i didnt downvote :)

Comment: We need to mutate the original object so what's the point? delete operator is made for it, and we use in on a copy... you can test the presence of the key before doing it...